trying to achieve an output format on Cpp as
I have the code below which works as expected. I am trying to achieve an output format like this
Enter number of input files: 6
Enter 1. file name: a.txt
Enter 2. file name: b.txt
Enter 3. file name: c.txt
Enter queried words in one line: Capitol impoverished
in Document a.txt, capitol found 2 times, impoverished found 1 times.
in Document b.txt, capitol found 1 times, impoverished found 1 times.

Yet when I run this code below, I get something like,
Enter number of input files: 2
Enter 1. file name: a.txt
Enter 2. file name: b.txt
Enter queried words in one line: capitol impoverished
in Document a.txt, capitol found 2 times.
in Document b.txt, capitol found 1 times.
Enter queried words in one line: in Document a.txt, impoverished found 1 times.
in Document b.txt, impoverished found 1 times.

It becomes messed up and for 1 txt file the findings should have printed within 1 line, 1 single line. Yet it messes up like this all the time. Note: I cannot use any libraries than std. What's the problem causing this how can I achieve what I want ? Thank you for your time.
This is the code, I didn't put the whole program as this is the only relevant part.
I fistly loop throught documents, via most outer loop, that is why it was supposed print in 1 single line for each txt document and not messed up like this.
while(1){
    string inputFromUser;
    vector<string> inputs;
    cout << "Enter queried words in one line: ";
    cin >> inputFromUser;
    istringstream iss(inputFromUser);
    string eachword;
    while(iss >> eachword){
        eachword = toLowerString(eachword);
        inputs.push_back(eachword);
    }
    
    for(int m = 0; m < allDocuments.size(); m++){ //looping to fit the output in the pdf.
    
        vector<string> foundOutputs;
        for(int l = 0; l < inputs.size(); l++){
            if(myTree.doesExist(inputs[l])){
                for(int z = 0; z < myTree.getWordItem(inputs[l])->documents.size(); z++){
                    if(allDocuments[m] == myTree.getWordItem(inputs[l])->documents[z].documentName){
                        foundOutputs.push_back(" " + inputs[l] + " found " + to_string(myTree.getWordItem(inputs[l])->documents[z].count));
                    }
                    //check for document
                }
            }
        
         }
        if(foundOutputs.size() != 0){
            cout << "in Document " << allDocuments[m] << ",";
            for(int k = 0; k < foundOutputs.size(); k++){
                cout << foundOutputs[k] << ((k == foundOutputs.size()-1)?" times.":" times,");
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }

}

UPDATE:
I updated my code like below, now I get a weird output like the first time i run the program..
Enter number of input files: 2
Enter 1. file name: a.txt
Enter 2. file name: b.txt
Enter queried words in one line: Enter queried words in one line: capitol 
in Document a.txt, capitol found 2 times.
in Document b.txt, capitol found 1 times.
Enter queried words in one line: cappp
No document contains the given query

For some reason it prints Enter queried words in one line:  twice.. Thank you in advance..
Here is the code
while(1){
    string inputFromUser;
    vector<string> inputs;
    cout << "Enter queried words in one line: ";
    getline(cin, inputFromUser);
    //cin >> inputFromUser;
    istringstream iss(inputFromUser);
    
    bool firstword = true;//checking for remove
    string eachword;
    while(iss >> eachword){
        //check REMOVE
        if( (firstword == true) && eachword == "REMOVE" ){
            iss >> eachword;
            myTree.remove(eachword);
            cout << eachword << " has been REMOVED\n";
            continue;
        }
        //check quit signal
        if( (firstword == true) && eachword == "ENDOFINPUT" ){
            exit(1);
        }
        
        firstword = false;
        
        eachword = toLowerString(eachword);
        inputs.push_back(eachword);
    }
    
    bool containsQuery = false;
    for(int m = 0; m < allDocuments.size(); m++){ //looping to fit the output in the pdf.
    
        vector<string> foundOutputs;
        //vector<int> foundCounts;
        for(int l = 0; l < inputs.size(); l++){
            if(myTree.doesExist(inputs[l])){
                for(int z = 0; z < myTree.getWordItem(inputs[l])->documents.size(); z++){
                    if(allDocuments[m] == myTree.getWordItem(inputs[l])->documents[z].documentName){
                        containsQuery = true;
                        foundOutputs.push_back(" " + inputs[l] + " found " + to_string(myTree.getWordItem(inputs[l])->documents[z].count));
                    }
                    //check for document
                }
            }
        
    }
    if(foundOutputs.size() != 0){
        cout << "in Document " << allDocuments[m] << ",";
        for(int k = 0; k < foundOutputs.size(); k++){
            cout << foundOutputs[k] << ((k == foundOutputs.size()-1)?" times.":" times,");
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

if((inputs.size() != 0)   && (containsQuery == false)){
    cout << "No document contains the given query\n";
}

}


How to read only one line from a file

I urge you to spend a little time learning to use a debugger. If you had stepped through the code to see what was happening you most likely would have noticed inputFromUser only had one word in it, or inputs.size() was 1.

For your new problem Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction? may help if you have code before this that you haven't shown that uses >> to read from std::cin. It's generally a bad idea to try and ask a followup question inside one that has already been answered. You can always ask a new one, and if you do focus on creating a [mcve] so nobody has to guess at the code they can't see.

If you want to read one line then use getline
cout << "Enter queried words in one line: ";
getline(cin, inputFromUser);

Your code is strange because you have valid code to split a line into words
istringstream iss(inputFromUser);
string eachword;
while(iss >> eachword){
    eachword = toLowerString(eachword);
    inputs.push_back(eachword);
}

but you failed to read a line in the first place
cout << "Enter queried words in one line: ";
cin >> inputFromUser;

cin >> inputFromUser; reads a word not a line. You then try to split that word into separate words, which doesn't make any sense.
Now it is possible that using getline will mess up the rest of your code (but obviously I cannot see the rest of your code). The reason for this is that getline consumes the newline at the end of the line it reads, but using >> does not consume the space or newline that separates the word it reads from the rest of the input. Therefore the two methods of reading leave the input in a slightly different state. But you have to use getline to achieve the result you want, so any consequences of that have to be solved as well.

much thanks, please see update for 1 last issue.

@Tufan That's probably because you have an unread newline in the input. This means the first getline reads that newline resulting in an empty line. Only on the second getline do you read some actual words. I guess that the unread newline is caused by some code before the code you have shown. So I can't say how to fix it. The mistake most people make is to read a number using >> and forget that reading a number does not read anything after the number including the newline that you type to end the number. So there will be an unread newline in the input stream.

@Tufan The bottom line is that to do C++ input you have to understand precisely what each operation does, what characters get read and importantly what characters don't get read. Most beginners just think 'my program asks for some input and then I type something' but that is not how input in C++ works.
